# 2D numpy array - extracting rows using for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have a 2D Numpy array. I want to count how many occurrences of the value 1 occur in the second column of the array. I then want to put each row which has value 1 in the second column into another array. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 1, 3], [2, 1, 5, 6], [1, 0, 7, 3]])

#count number of 1's in each column
col=np.count_nonzero(a==1, axis=0)

#extract how many 1's there are in the second column
PA=col[1]
CS = len(a)- PA

#Create array to put in rows of PA that have 1 in second column 
PA_Array = np.zeros([PA, 4])
CS_Array = np.zeros([CS, 4])

for row in PA_Array:
    for x in row:
        if x==1: 
            PA_Array[row, :] = a[row,:]
        else
            CS_Array[row, :] = a[row,:]

print(PA_Array)
```

I am having trouble with the for loop trying to extract the rows.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to do something like this?

```py
result = []
for row in a:
    if row[1] == 1:
        result.append(row)
result = np.array(result)
result
```

or as a one-liner,

```py
result = np.array([row for row in a if row[1]==1])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so much simpler.